# How to get a handle on users logging in with different methods

Tags: php, jquery, html, cordova

This is not a change my code question but something I can't get my head around.

I am making an app that does not need individual login in as such. How do you implement an auto login that does not require a sign in process.

The user requires their own database tables but the data is not personal.
I can use html storage but this can be wiped by the user. How do you get that individual token that would connect to the database tables. Can I get a phone ip? Etc. I'm not after code here just where I should be looking. I want to be able to distinguish between users(I.e ID in sql table) without making them sign up and log in as it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, there is nothing you can use that is permanent.

- You could set a cookie - user deletes the cookie.
- You could store everything in local data - user deletes local data.
- You could use an IP - lots of people use ISP's that have dynamic IP's.

None of these options would allow for getting the same data back for the user if logging in on a different device. If you used IP, on mobile users may switch between mobile data and/or various WIFI hotspots and have different IP's all the time.

It depends on how long the data needs to be stored. If it's OK for users to "lose" access to the data, maybe you'll just want to use a cookie.

One idea might be to have a random id that gets set into a cookie. On your page, you'll need to provide a link to a page that will re-set the cookie to access the previous data.

Comment: I have an app that does what I require but can not work out how it knows it's me? But always delivers my tables. There was no sign up process, I have wiped my data and it's still there. I'm equally bemused by how you can deliver content to people who sign in via face book? How do you know what tables to deliver? It looking like I will have to incorporate a single sign with HTML5 LS for auto log in. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the device UUID:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

This will only work on the supported devices however.

For doing this via the browser then this is trickier. See here for some possibilities: [Unique web browser identification ID for web control panel logins in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23827319/505722)

Comment: it looks useful but looks like iOS lets it down. Seem it can be over-written with an update ios(5.1) but it written in a way that it's behavior is an unknown. I still do not know how this app is doing it. Thanks for your help. I will look into this further and see if I can get it to work for me. I may have to do it with HTML5 for now and wait until they get this functionality available.