# Unique Device Identifier - Laravel

Tags: laravel, uuid

Is there any package or ways to use in detecting the device(s) ID the user is using? E.g. I wanna get the id of the device the user is logging in to.

I have a laravel app with a OTP/Google Authentication feature. After logging in, I automatically save the browser. Now, my problem is I wanna know what device ID is the user is using. I wanna know the identifier to it. So when I use another laptop with same model, and the browser is already saved in my database, my app will still ask OTP password from the user since it is a different device.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827319/unique-web-browser-identification-id-for-web-control-panel-logins-in-perl

Comment: also check this one out: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/browser-uuid-property/2042/19